# How to solve CannotCreateHold issue in preimage pallet?

Tags: solo-chain, opengov, preimage

I am adding the OpenGov to the POA solochain. In which we integrated preimage pallet with following configuration:

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const PreimageBaseDeposit: Balance = 1 * DOLLARS;
    pub const PreimageByteDeposit: Balance = 1 * CENTS;
    pub const PreimageHoldReason: RuntimeHoldReason = RuntimeHoldReason::Preimage(pallet_preimage::HoldReason::Preimage);
}

impl pallet_preimage::Config for Runtime {
    type WeightInfo = pallet_preimage::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type ManagerOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;

    type Consideration = HoldConsideration<
        AccountId,
        Balances,
        (),
        LinearStoragePrice<PreimageBaseDeposit, PreimageByteDeposit, Balance>,
    >;
}
```

After that When i am using the preimage pallet to create preimage then it is giving me CannotCreateHold error.

Any suggestion what should i update in config to make it work?

[image]